# Append column to QuickFix/J Logs database (Custom QuickFix/J Logger)

Tags: java, database, append, quickfix, quickfixj

QuickFix/J provides functionality to store its logs in database.

Is  it possible to append another column (business ID) to one of its table in such a way that it does not cause problems in QuickFix/J's internal message logging?

If it is possible kindly mention the procedure to do it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create your own Logger and LoggerFactory similar to the ones provided by QuickFix/J.

You can create a Logger by implementing the "quickfix.Log" interface, and a LoggerFactory by implementing the "quickfix.LogFactory" interface.

The easiest approach would be to use the private AbstractLog from QuickFix/J.

**Creating the Log class:**

> 1. Copy the [AbstractLog](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/AbstractLog.java) class as it is from QuickFix/J's source and include it in your project.
> 2. Create a class which extends the AbstractLog class and implement all the abstract methods.
> 3. Create member variables for any extra field you want to append to the logs (e.g. business ID), and provide a constructor which takes is
>      as an argument and sets its value.
> 4. The "logIncoming" and "logOutgoing" methods take a String parameter. This is the data you want to log. At this point you can
>      append your own fields (added in point 3) to the logs. You can format 
>      the log as you wish and you are free to use any method of output, i.e.
>      Console, database etc. as you will have to implement it yourself.

**Creating the LoggerFactory:**

> 1. Create a LoggerFactory that implements the quickfix.LogFactory interface.
> 2. In the "create" method, create and return the instance of the Logger you created before using the constructor you require.
> 3. The values that you need to be passed to the constructor can be kept as member variables of the LoggerFactory and set in
>      LoggerFactory's constructor.

You have a custom Logger now and can use it as QuickFix/J's own loggers are used, and QuickFix/J will automatically log using your logger.

```
ApplicationAdapter application = new FixInitiator();
SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings("./config/initiator.cfg");
CustomLogFactory customLogFactory = new CustomLogFactory(settings, myCustomID);
DefaultMessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();
FileStoreFactory fileStoreFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
socketInitiator = new SocketInitiator(application, fileStoreFactory, settings, customLogFactory, messageFactory);
socketInitiator.start();
```

Taking a look at QuickFix/J's own Logger and LoggerFactory implementations for help would be a good idea.
e.g. The Logger that Logs on Console:  [ScreenLog](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/ScreenLog.java), [ScreenLogFactory](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/ScreenLogFactory.java)

**QuickFix/J source:**

> https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj